# Crypto.encryptAES() throws InvalidKeyException

Tags: scala, encryption, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to encrypt a string using the private key `qp[vmauf;c[s.z/;vcS8DMN8H>K6J?dsr56lewqQ4WE?0FR.PV5>sa4pAS5NDF24SDK5SKMLVSX;DSAMKASMSADp[lqwe54352425`but i'm getting this exception:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 101 bytes
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCrypt.init(AESCrypt.java:87) ~[na:na]
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.ElectronicCodeBook.
            init(ElectronicCodeBook.java:93)~[na:na]
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:582) ~[na:na]
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:458) ~[na:na]
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.
            engineInit(AESCipher.java:307) ~[na:na]
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:797) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:859) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1229) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1166) ~[na:1.8.0]
        at play.api.libs.Crypto$.encryptAES(Crypto.scala:234) 
               ~[play_2.11-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
```

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
Crypto.encryptAES(name, privateKey)
```

I've changed the jars `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar` but still not working.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: This is a similar key, not the real one. Did you really made a useless comment like that? @Paul

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time someone had exposed a key by accident (for instance, http://it.slashdot.org/story/13/01/25/132203/github-kills-search-after-hundreds-of-private-keys-exposed)  But I'm glad to hear you haven't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.Crypto$) states:

> The private key must have a length of 16 bytes.

Even if you were to use the overload of `encryptAES` that uses the applications secret key, it actually will only use the first 16 characters. Why? Possible key lengths for AES are 128, 192, and 256 bits. Play's `Crypto` library only supports 128 bit keys (16 characters).